# Selenium Safari driver 2.48 gives error when initializing it

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I'm getting the below error when using selenium webdriver 2.48 (c#), safari driver 2.48.0 and safari 5.1.7 on windows:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.St
>   ring,System.Object]'.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide more details on this? Where is this exception thrown, at what does the code look like trying to invoke it -- also, what config or settings are being used?

Comment: I'm getting the error here...

IWebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();

I followed the steps mentioned here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

Comment: It looks like if I install webdriver and safari extension v2.45.0, everything works fine. But I need it to work with v2.48 as I use some functionality in that dll. Ref --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618243/using-selenium-webdriver-and-safari

Comment: What specific functionality?

Comment: For eg the following functions are not there in v2.45:
ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable
ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work with webdriver v2.47 and safari extension v2.48.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me are you still able to run test cases on Safari? Did you still using webdriver 2.47? Didn't you upgrade to the Webdriver 2.53.0? Thanks

Comment: I'm not using Safari right now. But I had got something to work as per my answer above.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have to automate it, so just wanted to confirm it with you before starting any automation.