# Does selenium webdriver 2.53.0 support safari on Windows?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, windows-8.1

I'm trying to automate my test suite on Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 8.1. I did install the extension provided in **Seleniumhq.org**. But I'm getting an error saying

Exception:

```
Did not receive a connection from the Safari extension. Please verify that it is properly installed and is the proper version..
```

I'm struggling with this since a very long time but didn't receive any help. Googled a lot but left unsuccessful. If anyone is automating safari on windows please help me.

Followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver).

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096075/selenium-safari-driver-2-48-gives-error-when-initializing-it?lq=1) post on SO, Is it worth downgrading for Safari? I could run my test suite on IE11, Firefox, Chrome and Opera. Can someone please guide me with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: if u have tested on chrome firefox and IE even opera then i think its not mandatory to do it with safari or in your case downgrade

Comment: But still if u like plz then have a look at http://elementalselenium.com/tips/69-safari

Comment: @rajNishKuMar They are asking me to do on Safari mainly. Because they are finding cross browser issues with Safari. From day 1 in this company I'm trying Safari but I couldn't.

Comment: ok let me try at my end

Comment: Thank you so much. As I'm trying on Windows and C# I couldn't find any latest solution. The solutions I found using Safari options and stuff got deprecated by Visual studio.

Comment: Sorry but i am not a C# guy i am java Guy

Comment: Also as per this **Official Document** https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver#getting-started **no latest version of safari is supported for windows** cause apple decided to **drop the idea to support windows**

Comment: So i guess to do automation you have to downgrade

Comment: Ya I did look that wiki post. I know Java. So if you can provide anything using Java I can try that with C#. Does downgrading Webdriver cause any issues? Will I miss any advantages of the latest versions? I'm the only automation tester and don't have any support, so bit worried to take a decision? I'm not much experienced as well.

Comment: ok let me try hope i can help you

Comment: I did try a sample project navigating to google and doing a search with webdriver 2.47. It did work. But Is it worth downgrading? Will I missing any features of the latest versions?

Comment: no i don't think so almost all functionality will work even u will not find any shortcomings and i am very glad that it worked for you hard work always pays keep it up

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I'm bit afraid to downgrade because I'm not sure whether safari will work on my application. Spoke to a developer, asked whether we can have 2 copies of project one for safari with webdriver 2.47 and the other for remaining browsers. Hope that works.

Comment: do one thing u make two copies of your automated test case one for safari only and one for rest run safari only when it is required otherwise stick to other one .everybody know support for safari by selenium is not official and also apple do not give support.even if some body says its require simply then for that we have to work on apple system not on windows

Comment: It's very unwise to downgrade in order to chase the 0.1% or 0.01% of users who use an officially unsupported Safari for Windows - and not a good use of your time.

Comment: Thank you @RajNishKuMar I have to implement the way. I asked my developer to guide me through that process.

Comment: @Andrew Regan, thank you for the response. I decided not to downgrade just for safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Selenium Webdriver 2.47, we can automate safari on windows platform. Source from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096075/selenium-safari-driver-2-48-gives-error-when-initializing-it?lq=1)